# How to check if next 3 consecutive rows in pandas column have same value?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with 3 columns - `id`, `date` and `value`.

```
| id | date | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | 1-04-2021 | 61 |
| 1001 | 3-04-2021 | 61 |
| 1001 | 10-04-2021 | 61 |
| 1002 | 11-04-2021 | 13 |
| 1002 | 12-04-2021 | 12 |
| 1015 | 18-04-2021 | 42 |
| 1015 | 20-04-2021 | 42 |
| 1015 | 21-04-2021 | 43 |
| 2001 | 8-04-2021 | 27 |
| 2001 | 11-04-2021 | 27 |
| 2001 | 12-04-2021 | 27 |
| 2001 | 27-04-2021 | 27 |
| 2001 | 29-04-2021 | 27 |
```

I want to check how many rows are there for each `id` where the next 3 or more than 3 next consecutive rows having the same value in `value` column? Once identified that the next 3 or more consecutive rows are having the same value, flag them as 1 in a separate column else 0.

So the final dataframe would look like the following,

```
| id | date | value | pattern
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | 1-04-2021 | 61 | 1 |
| 1001 | 3-04-2021 | 61 | 1 |
| 1001 | 10-04-2021 | 61 | 1 |
| 1002 | 11-04-2021 | 13 | 0 |
| 1002 | 12-04-2021 | 12 | 0 |
| 1015 | 18-04-2021 | 42 | 0 |
| 1015 | 20-04-2021 | 42 | 0 |
| 1015 | 21-04-2021 | 43 | 0 |
| 2001 | 8-04-2021 | 27 | 1 |
| 2001 | 11-04-2021 | 27 | 1 |
| 2001 | 12-04-2021 | 27 | 1 |
| 2001 | 27-04-2021 | 27 | 1 |
| 2001 | 29-04-2021 | 27 | 1 |
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with `groupby`:

```
df['pattern'] = (df.groupby(['id', df['value'].diff().ne(0).cumsum()])
                   ['id'].transform('size').ge(3).astype(int)
                )
```

Comment: but this should not be restricted to 3 consecutive rows, there could be more than 3 rows as well. Would it still work for the last flagged example?

Comment: It's `ge(3)` not `eq(3)` in the code. So yes, it works for the updated example.

Comment: ah nice, thanks. I just checked and this works. Can you please also explain in short what's actually happening here?

Comment: `df['value'].diff()` calculates the difference with the next row, `.ne(0).cumsum()` detects where the value changes. Then you groupby on `id` and on value changes and calculate the `size`. Then you compare the size with `3`...

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
def f(x):
    x = x.fillna(0)
    y = len(x)*[0]
    for i in range(len(x)-3):
        if x[i+1] == 0 and x[i+2] == 0:
            y[i] = 1
            y[i+1] = 1
            y[i+2] = 1
    if x[len(x)-1] == 0 and x[len(x)-2] == 0 and x[len(x)-3] == 0:
        y[len(x)-1] = 1
    return pd.Series(y)

df['value'].diff().transform(f)
```